# amazon.com initially fails to load on any browser, then suddenly works

Tags: networking, dns

I mostly use chrome, but I see this same weird behavior in firefox and edge.  In short, amazon.com fails to load, but usually, a few minutes later, the page suddenly loads and all subsequent browsing around amazon works fine.  I can't pin down exactly when it starts failing again, but it's definitely not when I restart the computer, i.e. it seems like it randomly fails and then randomly starts working again.  When it fails to load, I get:

> This site can’t be reached The webpage at https://www.amazon.com/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
> ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID

```
PS C:\Users\myuser> nslookup amazon.com
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.76.1

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    amazon.com
Addresses:  52.94.236.248
          54.239.28.85
          205.251.242.103

PS C:\Users\myuser> ping amazon.com

Pinging amazon.com [52.94.236.248] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 52.94.236.248: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=240
Reply from 52.94.236.248: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=240
Reply from 52.94.236.248: bytes=32 time=29ms TTL=240
Reply from 52.94.236.248: bytes=32 time=37ms TTL=240

Ping statistics for 52.94.236.248:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 29ms, Maximum = 37ms, Average = 33ms
```

This is only happening on 1 out of 7 computers on my LAN.  I've tried reinstalling chrome (even though it happens on all browsers), but still no luck.

Comment: Run TCP/IP Reset and test.   ...... Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer